# User defined data collection help ColdFusion

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, cfwheels

I am trying to figure out what is the best way to accomplish data collection.

Here is what I need to get accomplish:

I am building a CRM using ColdFusion & MySQL to collect data.

The data is different base on each user.

User Examples:

```
User 1: Collecting :: First Name, Last Name, Phone 1, Phone 2, Address
User 2: Collecting :: First Name, Middle Name, Last Name, Phone 1, City, State, Zipcode, Address
User 3: Collecting :: Bank Name, User Accounts, Business Name,  Address of Bank
```

To summarize What would be the best way to store it in MySQL and allow easy CRUD (Create, Retrieve, Update, Delete). How can i go about letting the user defined their data. Not to mention speed, pulling thousands of record per query by users interaction. Searching the Data etc...

Any example or answer is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example data, users 1 and 2 are actual users, and would store in a user table, that would contain all of those fields, but not all of them be required. User 3 is not really a user, it is an organization and would be best served by being stored in another table.

To be honest I think you're stretching too far here. It seems as if you're asking how to store objects without defining them, which is not really a suitable for a database system. The path you are on comes dangerously close to [an inner platform effect](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_Inner-Platform_Effect.aspx). Provide more useful structure suited to your customers needs. If they have to spend hours customizing your software to work for them, they'll end up choosing inferior software that is easier to use.

Comment: thanks for the input. The design I was thinking of was more predefined where the user will be able to select a a drop-down with predefined industry fields. Then give them the ability to relabel it to whatever they wish (if they want to). I just want to give them the ability to add new fields if they require more information to be collected. I do not want them to field they are stuck with the predefined fields.